# Calculating 5 card draw outs in Texas Hold'em Poker

Tags: python, math, statistics, simulation, poker

I am currently making a simulation about poker in python and I am stucked at calculating outs at post-flop, turn

I want to learn how to calculate the outs when flop is drawn.
In other way I want to learn how to make my simulation recognize that I need one card to have straight. If the missing card is in the middle, my outs would be 4. If it is at the beginning or end of the straight my outs would be 8.

For Example:

I have in my pocket(hands) 5-Spades and 6-Diamond

The flop is: 9-Clubs , 8-Hearts , K-Hearts

So my 5-Card hand is like: 5s - 6d - 8h - 9c - Kh

In Poker this draw is a gutshot straight draw. If I draw any kind of 7 in turn or river, I will have straight draw. Since there are 4 7s in a deck, my outs are 4 to have the Straight.

This is only one and basic example about outs.

If anyone can guide me, I will be pleased.

Kind Regards

Comment: Your question is worded in such a way that only people who play your version of poker will understand what you are asking. Since this limits your possible responses, you may want to reword your question--or at least define your terms--to get more responses.

Comment: Are you mixing 5 card draw with texas hold-em? There is no turn or river in 5 card draw, just a single draw after the first round of betting. In addition, you may want to ask to have this question migrated to poker.se, where there is more likely to be someone who can answer your question.

Comment: In flop, the board gets 3 more cards, so it is basically a 5-card draw and in texas hold'em poker the best 5 cards are being compared between players. So in a simply way, I just wanna know how to make my simulation recognize that I am 1 card away from straight, like in my giving example.

Comment: 5 card draw and flop games are completely different types of poker with different rules. You need to clarify your question and use the correct terms in order to get the right answer. Your title asks about calculating draw odds, but in a comment below, you indicate you are looking for something else.

Comment: David Bowling gave the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need some code that can recognize the various hands (four-of-a-kind, straight flush, etc.). Then, your algorithm should take four cards at a time from the player's hand, and cycle through all of the remaining cards in the deck, one at a time, adding them to the player's hand and testing them to see which hands are possible with one draw.

That is, given the hand `A B C D E`, so that cards `X1, X2, ..., X47` constitute the possible draws, your algorithm will test:

```
A B C D + (X1 ... X47) --> evaluate_hand()
A B C E + (X1 ... X47) --> evaluate_hand()
A B D E + (X1 ... X47) --> evaluate_hand()
A C D E + (X1 ... X47) --> evaluate_hand()
B C D E + (X1 ... X47) --> evaluate_hand()
```

If one of these 235 hands evaluates to `STRAIGHT_FLUSH`, you will know that the player is one card away from a straight flush.

Answer (score 0):

With no other knowledge you can work out the probabilities using

```
 number of ways a success can occur
 -----------------------------------
 total number of outcomes
```

So there are 5 cards you know about and 52-5 = 47 card you don't know giving 47 possible outcomes. To draw one of the 4 sevens the probability will be

```
   4
  --
  47
```

If two cards are drawn it, you then need to [probability tree diagrams](http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/maths/statistics/probabilityhirev1.shtml)

For the first two cards to be 7's the probability will be

```
   4 / 47 * 3 / 46
```

for the first to be a 7 and the second not to be a seven its

```
   4 / 47  * 43 / 46
```

for the first not to be a seven and the second to be a seven its

```
   43 / 47 * 4 / 46
```

for neither to be sevens its

```
   43 / 47 * 42 / 46
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, this is the calculation of odds (drawing one the 7s at turn), unfortunately I don't need this, I just need an algorithm to identify that I need a middle card to have straight.